# Dexie - Extend existing table with new fields

Tags: angular, dexie

I'm trying to modify the table structure of an existent table in my Angular2 application using Dexie.

The application already impements version 2 of the table, now I have to extend the mdValuta table with two new informations: f3, f4

This is the code:

```
super('WEB_IndexedDB');
this.version(1).stores({
  mdValuta:'codudm,numdec,numdecpre'
}); 
this.version(2).stores({
  mdValuta:'codudm,numdec,numdecpre,f1,f2'
});
this.version(3).stores({      
  mdValuta:'codudm,numdec,numdecpre,f1,f2,f3,f4'
});
```

I don't know why, when I'm executing the application I get this error in the console and no change has been applied to `mdValuta` table.

> OpenFailedError: ConstraintError A mutation operation in the
>   transaction failed because a constraint was not satisfied. For
>   example, an object such as an object store or index already exists and
>   a new one was being attempted to be created.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is in the *super('WEB_IndexedDB')* function... 
The following code works, creating a version-3 table:

```
var db = new Dexie ('WEB_IndexedDB');
db.version(1).stores({
  mdValuta:'codudm,numdec,numdecpre'
}); 
db.version(2).stores({
  mdValuta:'codudm,numdec,numdecpre,f1,f2'
});
db.version(3).stores({      
  mdValuta:'codudm,numdec,numdecpre,f1,f2,f3,f4'
});
db.open();
```